# finding single precision epsilon value in python

Tags: python

find the epsilon of the machine for both single-and double-precision floating point arithmetic.

i have done for double precision using the following code but not able to find single precision epsilon value in python though in c++ it comes out to be 5:960464*10**-8

```
import sys
import numpy as np

epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon/2.0

#Using the System Info, in python float is taken as double precision automatically    
print("Value of Machine epsilon double Precision  is:",epsilon)   


epsilon1 =1.0    #Using the while Loop, we see both values comes out to be same 
while(1+epsilon1!=1):
    epsilon1 = epsilon1*0.5 

print("Value of Machine epsilon double Precision  is:",epsilon1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
np.finfo(np.float32).eps
```